# How can I re render same template in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 templates in angularjs:

for routing purpose I am using UI router.

**I have two buttons**

1. button1 : On click of this template 1 will load and it will fetch
   data from my server.
2. button2 : On click of this template 2 will load
   and will fetch data from server.

Suppose I have click on button1 that time I am getting data from server and template1 will load but if I again click on same button1 then I can't updated data, means my previous loaded template1 is not re rendering again with new data.

I am doing routing by this line:

`location.search({'dataID':selectedDataId}).path('/listOfData');`

One more thing as I mention if I click on button1 that time I am getting url path with updated ID but template is not re rendering, so if reload page with that updated url then I am getting data.

Let me know how can I re-render same template with updated data.

Comment: Can you show as much relevant code as possible? Will be easier to understand your scenario.

Comment: yes please check this url here I have given relevant code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104651/re-render-same-angular-template

Please reply me as soon as possible.