# Re-render same angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1. When I am loading index.html page then by default UI router is loading home.html
   After click on name of home page data I am showing list.html page as a child template.
2. As per selected home data I am fetching data for list.html from server but here sample purpose I am not fetching data from server I have just shown skeleton of code, so currently I am just fetching data from static array.

Now when you click on any name column of home data then I am loading 2nd template(list.html) as child template and in console you will get "listController loaded" message but now when you again click on name column of home page data then my 2nd template is not re rendering and for testing purpose you can check console there you will not get console message again.

According to my scenario when user click on name column of home page data then that selected name I am passing as parameter to my server and according to that I am displaying data on 2nd template(list.html). This scenario is working perfectly for 1st time if I click again on name column of home page then my second template is not refreshing/reloading again  with new data

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body ng-app="demoApp">
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
<h2>Home Data</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Cost</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="data in homeData">
            <td ng-click="clickOfButton">{{ data.name }}</td>
            <td>${{ data.price }}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<div ui-view></div>
```

list.html

```
<h2>List Data</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Cost</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="data in listData">
            <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
            <td>${{ data.price }}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.js

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ["ui.router"]);
demoApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', 
    {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .state('home.list', 
    {
        url: '/:list',
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'listController'
    })

});
// This factory is used to fetch data for list.html from server.
demoApp.factory('demoFactory',function($q,$rootScope)
{  
    var demoFactoryObj = {};  
    demoFactoryObj.getData = function()
    {  

    }  
    return demoFactoryObj;  
});  

demoApp.controller('homeController',function( $scope,$location )
{  
     $scope.homeData = [
        {
            name: 'Macallan 12',
            price: 50
        },
        {
            name: 'Chivas Regal Royal Salute',
            price: 10000
        },
        {
            name: 'Glenfiddich 1937',
            price: 20000
        }
    ];
    $scope.clickOfButton = function()
    {
        $location.path('home/list');
    }

});
demoApp.controller('listController',function( $scope,demoFactory)
{  
    // When this controller will load then by default I am invoking this factory to get data from server. 
    //But currently I am showing you static demo.
    /*demoFactory.getData().then(function(result)
    {  
        $scope.listData = result;

    });*/
    console.log('listController loaded');
    $scope.listData = [
        {
            name: 'Abc',
            price: 50
        },
        {
            name: 'pqr',
            price: 10000
        },
        {
            name: 'xyz',
            price: 20000
        }
    ];

});
```

Comment: When clicking a column, how are you currently deciding which data to retrieve from the server? Are you passing it to the factory before calling `$location.path('home/list')`, or are you using `$stateParams`?

Comment: Before calling $location.path('home/list') I am storing selected column value in my service so when location.path('home/list') will invoke then my 2nd template controller will load and then I am fetching that store parameter from service then I am passing parameter to factory method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject `$state` instead of `$location` and use `$state.go`:

```
$scope.clickOfButton = function() {
  $state.go('home.list', { list: 'someName' }, { reload: true });
}
```

Where `someName` is what you want showing in the URL:

```
/#/home/someName
```

To retrieve the value of the list parameter you can inject `$stateParams` and access it like this:

```
demoApp.controller('listController', function($scope, demoFactory, $stateParams) {

  console.log($stateParams.list);
```

Comment: Thanx for reply but how to get url parameter value using $location. In my earlier case, I am providing parameter name in url but according to your suggested way we are not providing parameter name, so how to get parameter value from url?

Comment: When I asked you only wrote that before calling $location.path you store the selected column in your service. You didn't say you need the parameter to be passed with the URL. You need to be more specific how you are currently handling it for me to help.

Comment: yes sorry for this, Currently according to suggested approach I am using $state.go('home.list', { list: 'someName' }, { reload: true });

Now when 'home.list' will load then in home.list controller I want to fetch parameter of url in above case I have to access 'someName' then how we can do that?

Comment: Updated my answer with how to retrieve the value in the `listController`.

Comment: According to above approach if I am using following line of code for routing purpose:
$state.go('home.list', { list: 'someName' }, { reload: true });

when I am going to load list template then my home template is also reloading. How we can avoid to reloading home template? 

Note: I want to load list template under home template.